# MonoGame xna to ios examples?

Tags: monogame, walkthrough

I've been trying to figure out how to do this port and I need a walk-through. A detailed soup to nuts example would be great. [Edit] I should add that I want to port a WP7 game...

Answer (score 0):

Each target platform is handled differently

Maybe some videos would help
This one ports to Android http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF0sm5KGPPM
this one ports to win 8 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ycmeVYm_gI

It might help installing the [installer](http://monogame.codeplex.com/downloads/get/391305), (it installs the templates for VS and other sutff)